# CONNECT_PROC in HADR Environment causing -1776 DB2 Error

Tags: db2

we have what appears to be a pretty unique scenario with DB2/HADR.

We are using a connect_proc to monitor logins to the database and bounce the hostname of the connection against a table of valid hostnames.  If the hostname is in that list access is granted and logged, if the hostname is not in that list a 20001 error is returned with "ACCESS RESTRICTED".

Our issue is with connecting to the database:

Lets assume our connection string is this:
jdbc:db2://host3:1000/vpcdb:clientRerouteAlternateServername=host3,host2,host1;clientRerouteAlternatePortNumber=1000,1000,100;queryCloseImplicit=2;enableSeamlessFailover=yes;enableClientAffinitiesList=yes;blockingReadConnectionTimeout=1200;

If host1 is the primary HADR DB, we receive the 1776, if host3 is the primary HADR DB we gain access.

If the trigger is disabled using: update db cfg using connect_proc NULL@ access is granted

Multiple DB2 drivers have been used specifically: 4.14.111 and 4.13.80.  The other interesting thing here is that either configuration above works in Squirrel with the trigger active but not when used as a connector in activemq or any of our other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the `CONNECT_PROC` configuration parameter has been set as expected on the secondary server (host3), too?

Not all changes to the database configuration are replicated via HADR, so you would need to manually update the configuration on the standby host, too.